# How to declare a variable/param of type "Control implementing interface ISomething"?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, controls, interface

I wish to declare a variable in such a way as it can be assigned only values which derive from Control and also implement the ISomething interface.

I intend to add the ISomething interface to derivatives of controls.

I would like to derive SpecialTextBox and SpecialDatePicker From TextBox and DatePicker and implement the ISomething interface on each.

I would like to be able to assign each of these controls to a variable whose type is "Control which also implements ISomething" so that from there they could either have their ISomething methods invoked or could be added to a control collection on a form.

**So.... How do I declare a variable of Type "Control which also implements ISomething"**?

Ideally the answer to be in VB.Net but I would be interested in a C# method also.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to do this is with generics - i.e. a generic method:

```
void Foo<T>(T control) where T : Control, ISomething
{
    // use "control"
    // (you have access to all the Control and ISomething members)
}
```

Now you can call Foo **only** with other variables that are a `Control` that implements `ISomething` - you don't need to specify the generic, though:

```
Foo(someName);
```

is all you need. If you've given it something that isn't both a `Control` and `ISomething`, the compiler will tell you.

---

Update: I don't "do" VB, but reflector tells me that the above translates as:

```
Private Sub Foo(Of T As { Control, ISomething })(ByVal control As T)

End Sub
```

Comment: It's going to take a moment for me to comprehend this but it's what I'm after

Comment: erm cannot delete previous comment to restate it... I meant "...but (I suspect) it's ..."

Comment: So if I understand this correctly... Within the scope of this method...the Type T will meet my requirements.... Well Damn that's good enough... Thanks very much... Great stuff. I can see why your rep is so high :)

Comment: That is exactly what the generic constraints mean, yes. Within Foo, you are guaranteed that the type T (supplied by the caller) meets those conditions.

Comment: I don't suppose you can inherit from a generic constraint? :D

Comment: Just tried this out...
Public Class ControlFactory
    Public Function CreateControl(Of T As {Control, ISControl})() As T
        Return New STextBox 'This not allowed :(
    End Function
End Class
Public Class STextBox
    Inherits Control
    Implements ISControl
End Class

Comment: Do you want to create objects inside the method? In which case, add `, new()` to the constraints (`, New` in VB) and you can use `new T()` in the method (with similar VB). So if you call it with a <STextBox> generic-type-argument, you will get a new STextBox